# Error message rendered only after pressing Enter key

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to render validation messages. The trick I'm working on is that the messages appear only after pressing Enter key (not after submit button!). After that it works correctly.

Here's what I did at the JSF side (some parts have been omitted for simplicity) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
<body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form id="idForm">
            <h:panelGrid width="100%"
                rendered="#{not empty declarationReglementaireModel.detailCurrentDecReg.decReg.listLigneGldsDTO}">

                <rich:extendedDataTable id="listGLD" iterationStatusVar="itGLD"
                    rows="50"
                    value="#{declarationReglementaireModel.detailCurrentDecReg.decReg.listLigneGldsDTO}"
                    var="ligneGLD" frozenColumns="1" style="height:300px; width:920px;"
                    selectionMode="none">

                    <rich:column width="35px">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">
                            <a4j:commandLink render="editGridGLD" execute="@this"
                                oncomplete="#{rich:component('modifGLD')}.show()">
                                <span class="icone icone-edit icone-align-center" />
                                <a4j:param value="#{itGLD.index}"
                                    assignTo="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneGldIndex}" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                    target="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneGld}"
                                    value="#{ligneGLD}" />
                            </a4j:commandLink>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Montant encaissement exercice" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <div style="text-align: right">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ligneGLD.mtEncaissesExercice}">
                                <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="€" groupingUsed="true"
                                    maxFractionDigits="2" type="currency" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </div>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Montant réductions exercice" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <div style="text-align: right">
                            <h:outputText value="#{ligneGLD.mtReducExercice}">
                                <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="€" groupingUsed="true"
                                    maxFractionDigits="2" type="currency" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </div>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Date PACA" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ligneGLD.dtPaca}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="Europe/Paris" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Numéro OLAF" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ligneGLD.noOlaf}">
                        </h:outputText>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column width="200px">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Origine titre" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ligneGLD.origineTitre}">
                        </h:outputText>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Contentieux" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{ligneGLD.boContentieux}">
                        </h:outputText>
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:extendedDataTable>

                <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="liste">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText id="paginationCompteurGLD"
                            value="Ligne #{composantPaginationGLDBack.firstElement} à #{composantPaginationGLDBack.lastElement} sur #{composantPaginationGLDBack.nbTotalElements}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <rich:popupPanel header="Données modifiables" id="modifGLD"
                domElementAttachment="form" autosized="true" zindex="500"
                left="auto" top="auto">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="editGridGLD">
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="bloc-contenu-message " layout="block">
                        <rich:messages />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="6" cellspacing="10"
                        styleClass="criteresSaisie" rowClasses="critereLigne"
                        columnClasses="titreCourtColonne,,titreCourtColonne,,titreCourtColonne,">

                        <h:outputLabel for="GLDdtDeclCreanceMandataire"
                            value="Date déclaration mandataire" />
                        <rich:calendar id="GLDdtDeclCreanceMandataire" inputSize="8"
                            value="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneGld.dtDeclCreanceMandataire}"
                            enableManualInput="true" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            showInput="true">
                        </rich:calendar>

                        <h:outputLabel value="Montant réductions exercice" />
                        <h:inputText
                            value="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneGld.mtReducExercice}"
                            onchange="this.value=this.value.replace(/\./g,',')" size="10">
                            <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" type="number" />
                        </h:inputText>

                        <h:outputLabel for="GLDdtPaca" value="Date PACA" />
                        <rich:calendar id="GLDdtPaca" inputSize="8"
                            value="#{declarationReglementaireModel.currentLigneGld.dtPaca}"
                            enableManualInput="true" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            showInput="true">
                        </rich:calendar>


                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <div align="right">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="8">
                                <a4j:commandButton value="Enregistrer"
                                    action="#{rechercheDecRgltCtrl.enregistrerLigneGLD}"
                                    render="editGridGLD" execute="modifGLD"
                                    oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) {#{rich:component('modifGLD')}.hide();}" />
                                <a4j:commandButton value="Annuler"
                                    onclick="#{rich:component('modifGLD')}.hide(); return false;" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </div>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </rich:popupPanel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `render="editGridGLD, editGridGLD"` has the same ID two times.

Comment: I made a mistake, I edited the post.

Comment: Not that it is clear what exactly you're asking for but wouldn't it be easier to hide the messages if the submit button was clicked?

Comment: @Makhiel the problem is that I have no message until I press the enter key

Comment: And you want them to appear when? During input?

Comment: Yes, I want to appear them when I click submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a4j:support to sent request when you want,
like onblur / onkeyup ... or any javascript the item supported.
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html